# ASP.NET Core : URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

In a production environment which is preferable to rewrite ASP.NET Core URLs

- URL Rewrite module with IIS
- Apache mod_rewrite module
- NGINX Rewrite
- URL Rewrite middleware

Does URL Rewrite middleware reduce the performance of an app?

Comment: According to [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0) yes: `URL rewriting can reduce the performance of an app. Where feasible, limit the number and complexity of rules.`